# Mixing constructors with fixed parameters and constructors with constructor templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Is it possible to mix constructors with fixed parameters and constructor templates?

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
    public:
        Test(std::string, int, float) {
            std::cout << "normal constructor!" << std::endl;
        }

        template<typename ... Tn>
        Test(Tn ... args) {
            std::cout << "template constructor!" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Test t("Hello World!", 42, 0.07f);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me "template constructor!". Is there a way, that my normal constructor is called?

Comment: Exactly what type should the compiler interpret the string to be?

Comment: @Captain Obvlious: I don't understand your question, but I see now that "Hello World!" is interpreted as a char * and not a std::string and, thus, the template constructor is used.

Comment: @gartenriese: It's not "interpreted"... it **is** a `const char *`. The template doesn't do any interpreting for you. I think that's what C.O. wanted to point out.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually, the real type is `const char(&)[6]`, not `const char*`.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Yes, though curiously you cannot tell those two apart by means of overload resolution!

Comment: @KerrekSB What am I [missing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef7154a32a50bc3c)?

Comment: @DanielFrey: Remove the reference from the `char const *`. Decay produces rvalues. But I see now that I didn't make my point very well. (It was more like "suppose you already have the pointer version and want to add a way to handle arrays".)

Comment: @DanielFrey: Ah, [here is what I meant](http://ideone.com/3enzRP): Once you have the pointer overload, you cannot get at the template-array one. (And also if you change the pointer overload to `char const * const &`.)

Comment: @KerrekSB I see and yes, there are only some cases where you can use a hack/approximation but you can't really use overload resolution in a reliable way to keep both apart. Which is quite sad as it would have some good uses. Another dark corner where C++'s legacy shows... :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, in the event of two equally good matches, the non-template is preferred:

```
Test t(std::string("Hello"), 42, 0.07f);
```

Comment: That's an interesting `std::string(const char*, int, float) ` constructor.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: Shh... :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer. If you correct your brackets, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Just so the OP knows: `"Hello World!"` requires a conversion from `char const*` to `std::string`, while the templatized version will deduce the type and use that one. An overload which doesn't require a conversion is always preferable to one that does, so the constructor template is chosen in this case.

Answer (score 3):

C++ knows two basic string types: `std::string` and *null*-terminated character arrays. Instead of fixing your problem on the caller's side (as Kerrek SB suggested), you could add another overload:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(std::string, int, float) {
        std::cout << "normal constructor!" << std::endl;
    }

    Test(const char*, int, float) {
        std::cout << "normal constructor 2!" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename ... Tn>
    Test(Tn ... args) {
        std::cout << "template constructor!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f065c0c613a442f)

You could also use delegating constructors to implement one of the normal constructors in terms of the other to avoid duplicating the code, e.g.

```
Test(const char* c, int i, float f)
    : Test(std::string(c), i, f)
{
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3832217ca328f95)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of delegating constructors! I would upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry!