# Templates and std::pair list-initialization

Tags: c++, templates

This is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894459/mixing-constructors-with-fixed-parameters-and-constructors-with-constructor-temp) question.

Why does this compile:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test {
    public:
        Test(std::pair<char *, int>) {
            std::cout << "normal constructor 2!" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Test t6({"Test", 42});
    return 0;
}
```

But this does not:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test {
    public:
        Test(std::pair<char *, int>) {
            std::cout << "normal constructor 2!" << std::endl;
        }
        template<typename ... Tn>
        Test(Tn ... args) {
            std::cout << "template constructor!" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Test t6({"Test", 42});
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

> error: call to constructor of 'Test' is ambiguous

As I understood in the previous question, the non-template constructor is preferred, if it exactly matches. So I guess {"Test", 42} does not match with std::pair?
If so, **what would be the correct way?** I know there is std::make_pair, but I want it as short as possible, because I can have several of those pairs and typing std::make_pair everytime would be unfavorable, because it bloats things. So **what is the shortest way possible?**

Comment: The code doesn't compile because you're missing a `;` after the class definition :-) And the first argument type for the `pair` should be `char const *` if you're going to pass a string literal to it (because the conversion to `char *` is deprecated). After fixing all that, I can get [clang to compile your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84054c90d130c020) by making the variadic template constructor `explicit`, but gcc still fails to compile it. Not sure who is correct in this case.

Comment: @Praetorian That's why I was confused because I was only experiencing that behavior on GCC.

Comment: @Praetorian Sorry, nevermind. It does compile on clang. But why does it go with the `pair` constructor?

Comment: Fixed the semicolon.
I use clang, so it compiles, when i add explicit.
When I only have the explicit template constructor, I get 
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Test'

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm guessing it's because of what you said earlier, that template argument deduction doesn't work with braced-init-lists. Somehow the presence of that implicit variadic template constructor is allowing creation of temporaries that then match the copy & move constructors. [This](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/05/is_related.html) might contain the answer but I don't have time to try all that out right now.

Comment: `{"Test",42}` means "anything that can be constructed from a string literal and an int". It does not mean `std::pair<const char*,int>`. So you must specify explicity that you want a `std::pair`. You could define your own inline function `mp` that calls `std::make_pair` to make your call shorter: `Test t6(mp("Test",26));`.

Comment: If you want the shortest solution, just provide a 2 parameter constructor taking a `const char*` and an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using c++11, switch to brace initialization and your code will compile under gcc (4.7.2 at least) and do what you want:

```
...
int main() {
    Test t6{{"Test", 42}};
    return 0;
}

$ g++ t.cpp -std=c++11
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:14:25: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

$ a.out
normal constructor 2!
```

Comment: True. It works under GCC 4.8.2 and Clang 3.3 as well. I wonder why. Is there a rule that causes list-initialization to treat constructor templates differently?