# assignment operator on empty inizializer_list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, initializer-list, overload-resolution, compiler-bug

can you explain how STL containers handle assignment operator with empty initializer list?

when i'll do something like this:

```
vector<int> v;
v = { };
```

the function that is called is **not**:

```
vector& operator= (initializer_list<value_type> il);
```

but:

```
vector& operator= (vector&& x);
```

on the other hand, when i'll do something similar with my own class:

```
struct A {
    A& operator= (const A&) { return *this; }
    A& operator= (A&&) { return *this; }
    A& operator= (initializer_list<int>) { return *this; }
};

/* ... */

A a;
a = { };
```

the code does not compile on VS2013, and says:

```
error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
```

if the list is not empty, it works fine, it just calls the function with initializer list. the problem appears only when the list is empty, on vector it calls the rvalue assignment operator, on my class it gives error.

how this situation is handled in vector and other containers?

Comment: Neither `gcc` nor `clang` have the same error but confirmed error with [vs](http://rextester.com/ZWD57818).

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd78ac29f69fdc05).

Comment: g++ and clang++ unambiguously select the `initializer_List<int>` overload of `operator=`. I think this is correct: according to [over.ics.list], the conversion rank of this overload should be Exact Match. For the reference overloads, a temporary has to be created, so the reference (probably) doesn't bind directly; therefore the conversion sequence is a User-Defined Conversion. (Note the section [over.ics.ref], where this is defined, doesn't mention list-init; it might be underspecified.)

Comment: @dyp that is what I was thinking

Comment: @dyp so reference binding refers back to `8.5.3` which enumerates the direct binding cases which do not include `initializer_list` so we fall back to `8.5` which will bring us to `8.5.4` for *list-initializaton* so I don't think it is under specified, perhaps convoluted.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I think I found an interesting interpretation of the note in [over.ics.list]/6 "[*Note:* The rules in this section will apply for
initializing the underlying temporary for the reference. — *end note*]" I think that note says that we shall apply [over.ics.list] to the temporary which is created and then bound via 13.3.3.1.4 to the reference (class prvalue bound to ref = direct binding). Applying [over.ics.list] to an empty braced-init-list initializing a class type is covered by /4, which says it's ranked as an UDC.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Actually, that works the way you suggested: via 8.5.4 :D I keep forgetting 13.3.3.* is not concerned with how initialization is performed, but only with ranking of ICS.

Comment: @dyp I finally answered this, I kept running out of time every time I tried to finish it up. I would appreciate a second eye, I doubt it will get a lot of views.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it looks like there are two active bugs that may be related. The first one sounds the most similar but we can not see the code. It is probably worth it to add a comment on your problem, it may help to get the problem resolved faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug clang(*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8b7e0042fed07dd)*) and gcc(*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c126fb9a976b112)*) accept this program and choose the *std::initializer_list* overload which looks correct since that is an *exact match*, this is covered in the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section section `13.3.3.1.5` *List-initialization sequence* paragraph *2* from the example:

```
void f(std::initializer_list<int>);
f( {1,2,3} ); // OK: f(initializer_list<int>) identity conversion
f( {’a’,’b’} ); // OK: f(initializer_list<int>) integral promotion
f( {1.0} ); // error: narrowing
```

we have an *identity conversion* which is an *exact match*.

For the reference overloads we go to paragraph *5* it says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> Otherwise, if the parameter is a reference, see 13.3.3.1.4. [ Note: **The rules in this section will apply for initializing the underlying temporary for the reference**. —end note ]

indicates that temporary is created an then we can apply the rules to resulting temporary. This will be a *User-defined conversion* which is worse than an *exact match*.

So this should not be ambiguous.

**Update**

Looks like there are two active bugs related to this:

- [Compiler confused about whether to use a initializer_list assignment operator](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792355/compiler-confused-about-whether-to-use-a-initializer-list-assignment-operator)
- [VC++ 12 RC fails to choose between initializer_list enabled assignment operator and canonical one for std::pair list elements](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806184/vc-12-rc-fails-to-choose-between-initializer-list-enabled-assignment-operator-and-canonical-one-for-std-pair-list-elements)

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, however I think (as discussed in the comments to the OP), that neither 13.3.3.1.4 nor 8.5.3 can be applied to find out whether it's directly or indirectly binding (they talk about argument expressions). Rather, I'd say that the note in 13.3.3.1.5/6 (the one about references) indicates that a temporary is created from the `{}` (via 8.5.4, ranked as UDC as per 13.3.3.1.5/5), and then bound directly (8.5.3 "If the initializer expression is [...] a class prvalue", ranked as Exact Match as per 13.3.3.1.4/1). Also see 13.3.3.1.1/3

Comment: @dyp I see what you mean, although I think you mean the note in `13.3.3.1.5/5` which says *Note: The rules in this section will apply for initializing the underlying temporary for the reference. —end note*.

Comment: The numbering depends on which draft you're using ;) in the latest from the github repo, they've split the `initializer_list` and array parts into two paragraphs.

Comment: +1 for correctness of the answer and the links to bug reports. But you should quote more from 13.3.3.1.5, to make clear that: 1) In the `f({1,2,3})` example, not only the conversion of `1`, `2` and `3` are each identity conversions, but the conversion of the whole list is, too. That wasn't obvious to me until I read the text of 13.3.3.1.5/2. 2) You need 13.3.3.1.5/3 to show that calling a constructor for `vector` is really a user-defined conversion. 3) For completeness sake, 13.3.3.2/2 to make clear that a standard conversion is always preferred to a user-defined conversion.

Comment: Oh, and 5.17/9, which states that `z = {1,2};` is equivalent to `z.operator({1,2});`. That doesn't follow from the usual rules, because `{1,2}` is not an expression.

Comment: @jogojapan will do, just not sure when I will have the chance to do it but I will update and clarify.